# How to prevent backspace string "\b\0\b" from being printed to console while typing in password

Tags: vb.net, console, passwords

I came up with a VBA function that allows the user to input a password and each keypress also prints a corresponding asterisk. I figured that printing "\b\0\b" brings the "cursor" back, prints a null character to overwrite the asterisk in that position and brings the cursor back once again.

```
    Private Function GetPassword() As String
        Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
        While (True)
            Dim ki = Console.ReadKey(True)
            If (ki.Key = ConsoleKey.Enter) Then
                Console.WriteLine()
                Exit While
            End If
            If (ki.Key = ConsoleKey.Backspace) Then
                If (sb.Length > 0) Then
                    Console.Write("\b\0\b")
                    sb.Length -= 1
                End If
                Continue While
            End If
            Console.Write("*")
            sb.Append(ki.KeyChar)
        End While
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
```

To test it out I typed in the correct password let's say: "Abc123" and added an extra character to end up with "Abc1234".

I pressed backspace to correct my mistake and the "\b\0\b" string was printed though the password was accepted so I'm assuming this is working.

Is there any way to keep this functionality intact yet avoid printing the backspace string directly to the console?

Comment: VB does not recognize escape sequences like `\b`.  Instead you can try `Console.WriteLine(Chr$(8) & Chr$(0) & Chr$(8))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
If (ki.Key = ConsoleKey.Backspace) Then
    If (sb.Length > 0) Then
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop)
        Console.Write(" ")
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop)
        sb.Length -= 1
    End If
    Continue While
End If
```

It moves the cursor one step to the left (back one character) and then prints a space which moves the cursor back to the right (original position). It then moves the cursor again to the left to stand on the space.

Here is another solution (based comments by @ChrisDunaway):

```
If (ki.Key = ConsoleKey.Backspace) Then
    If (sb.Length > 0) Then
        Console.Write(Chr(8) & Chr(0) & Chr(8))
        sb.Length -= 1
    End If
    Continue While
End If
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I'm guessing the `Console.WriteLine("\b \b")` solution multiple people proposed was intended to work despite printing the string to the console?

Comment: I don't know. I tried that solution and it prints these characters to the console. Maybe there is a way to make them not appear in the console.

Comment: The problem is that VB does not recognize \b as a backspace like c# does.  In VB, you need to use `Chr$(8)`